# Comentarios en JSON

Tags: json

¿Existe la posibilidad de poner comentarios en JSON?
El IDE me permite ponerlos, pero avisa que no se puede poner estos comentarios. ¿Hay otra manera de poder indicar aclaraciones?

Muchas gracias !! [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lamentablemente Json no puede contener comentarios, al menos ajenos a la estructura que lo compone.
Podrías usar un elemento para tal uso y excluirlo en tu modelo al serializar/deserializar.

Comment: Correcto, se puede poner una propiedad destinada a comentarios e ignorarla al momento de serializar / deserializar. Me parece que algunas librerías como Gson ya contemplan esa posibilidad. Ver [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244858/5587982) y los comentarios en ella para más detalles.

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo tendré en cuenta para implementarlo